# Tile engine performance issue

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using SFML and I can't find any explanation on how the library is working and I have performance issues.
I am trying to make a tile map made of 50x50 tiles that are each 20x20 pixels wide.
1) Each tile is a sf::sprite whose graphic image is simply a big image (my tileset), on which I set a 20x20 subrectangle.
2) I am simply looping over total number of tiles and using App.Draw(Map[i][j]); to draw each tile, and I am using "view" objects so I can move the view around

Now I have a very low FPS (1 image / second) and I am wondering 2 things in relation to the previous points.
1) Is it that each sf::sprite takes time to draw because their image is coming from a huge image that was cropped?
2) Am I right to loop over the whole set of tiles, even the ones I am not seeing? I am assuming that the view object makes it so that the tiles that are out of view are not re-computed in vain

thanks

Comment: Show us how you render your map, (post some code), this shouldn't happen. Also, are you cropping the tiles at every iteration or at program start?

Comment: I'm simply doing:
  for(int i=0; i < sizeX; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j < sizeY; j++) {

    App.Draw(Map[i][j]);
   }
  } . As I said I am assuming that the objects out of the "view" should not be "computed" when I am calling Draw on them

Comment: Even using 20 by 20 tiles (this does not even fill the screen), I get 20 FPS while scrolling, which seems way too low

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SFML, but you should try only drawing things that are visible. Most graphic libraries do not do this, as the client can do it more efficiently. Also, make sure that SFML is using hardware accelerated rendering and not software blitting.

Comment: Without any code, the answer is you are doing it wrong.  Try a profiler.  Hazarding a guess you are binding textures every frame.  SFML uses Opengl in the background so it is fairly fast unless you do something that is dumb to do in opengl.

Comment: SFML indeed does _not_ do any viewport culling on its own. You can look that up in the [source code](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML). Apart from that I have to assent the previous comment: you're doing something wrong. In a [simple example](http://www.pastie.org/2662053) I get around 40 frames per second for drawing 16384 sprites of 32×32 pixels each from a 4096×4096 "tileset" on a 800×600 viewport -- without culling. With culling I get over 1000 f/s (on a GF 560 Ti/Windows 7). Also see the example code for how to do simple viewport culling.

Comment: Using your code, SFML 1.6 and a spritesheet of 170 sprites, I have 17 FPS using the debug config and 400 using the release config. I am on a laptop with virtually no GPU so I guess this is normal then

Comment: 400 frames per second doesn't sound too bad, does it? I forget to mention that I used a release config. When using a debug config I only get 14 f/s even with culling.

Comment: ok then, I thought that everyone was using the debug config for testing purposes... problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally considered the wrong way to render a tile map.

The more correct way is to create a large texture, or `sf::Image` in this case, and then rendering your tiles onto this texture, and then rendering this large texture to the screen. There are cases where this approach isn't feasible, but for most cases, it's much better.

This way, you only render each tile once when the tile map is loaded, and then you only need to render the large texture once for each frame, as opposed to rendering 2500 individual tiles for each frame.

The way SFML uses OpenGL isn't friendly to large numbers of `Draw()` calls, so it helps to find ways to call it as few times as possible.

Comment: It should also be noted that SFML 2 will optimize this. Maybe it's already been implemented actually, it's been a while since I used a tile engine with SFML.